# Date validation JS

Tags: javascript, date, validation, momentjs

I have to make a date validation in 'DD/MM/YYYY' format. The date must:

- not be in the past
- be maximum 6 months in future

It works fine, but it takes the current day as an invalid date.
I tried a lot of things, but I can't figure it out why. Maybe the problem is in if construction...

```
let daaa = moment(new Date()).date();
let daaad = moment(new Date()).date();
alert(moment(daaad).isSame(daaa));
```

also try `new Date().getTime() and getDate()`

```
const selectedDate = new Date(value.split('/').reverse().join('-'));
let today = new Date(Date.now());
let plusSixMonths = new Date(Date.now());
plusSixMonths.setMonth(plusSixMonths.getMonth() + 6);
if (selectedDate >= today && plusSixMonths > selectedDate) return true;
```

I expected to catch also the current date in valid dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by `Date.now()`, it includes the current time. So if you're checking `28/10/2019` then 2019-10-28T00:00:00 is almost certainly before today's date with a time component:

```
(selectedDate >= today && plusSixMonths > selectedDate)
```

becomes

```
(2019-10-28T00:00:00 >= 2019-10-28T11:02:32 && 2020-04-28T11:02:32 > 2019-10-28T00:00:00)
```

Which is going to be `false`.

You'll need to remove the time components from `today` (`new Date()` also gets the current time as a date object)

```
let today = new Date();
// set hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to zero i.e. 12am
today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Then you should be able to make the comparison as you expected.

***Update*** Thanks to RobG for pointing out that setHours can also set minutes, seconds and milliseconds.

Comment: @dist If the answer resolved your problem please upvote and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here and yes , the answer is perfect for me. Works fine. but my vote wont appear because I don't have  enough reputation .

Comment: That can be somewhat shorter as `today.setHours(0,0,0,0)`. ;-)